# Profiler: every page load produces twice entries in aoe profiler runs grid. Is frontend "executed" twice?

Tags: magento-1.7, performance, debugging, profiler

I'm currently doing some bottleneck hunting on my M1.
I've installed AOE Profiler.
I do some test on category page.

In the backend (System > AOE Profiler) I noticed there is twice entries at every page run (with a delay of ~3 seconds)!

Is that normal (profiling related)?
If not, means my performance problems are probably caused by this...

Thank you for your feedback.

[image]